# Add plugin to firefox using windows registry

Tags: firefox, plugins, browser, firefox-addon

I am following [Adding Extensions using the Windows Registry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Adding_Extensions_using_the_Windows_Registry#Plugins) tutorial to install plugin in firefox.

i have added key at this loacation.
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\plugin-id

Unfortunately, plugin is listing in chrome and not in firefox. any idea?

Comment: Please post the actual content of the key.

Comment: @xyz.com/helloworld is key, contains string Path of type REG_SZ, it contains the nphelloworld.dll path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [FireBreath](https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath), FireBreath is a cross-platform browser plugin framework. It supports ActiveX and NPAPI on Windows, Mac OS X, and Linux (probably other unix-derivitives as well).